# UWP - Load image in class library

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a Universal Windows application that hosts a main menu. I want a plugin architecture, where the menu items are added from class libraries.

But I can't seem to load images correctly. I can't get the `ms-appx:///` working, and when I try to add the images as an embedded resource, it hangs:

```
var assembly = typeof(CookModule).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
using (var imageStream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("My.Namespace.Folder.ImageName-100.png"))
using (var raStream = imageStream.AsRandomAccessStream())
{
    var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
    bitmap.SetSource(raStream); //<- Hangs here
```

I get no exceptions, errors in the output or anything. It just hangs there, and the app simply doesn't load the page.

I have also tried:

```
var bitmap = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Folder/ImageName-100.png"));
```

I'm missing something similar to the WPF pack uri's where I can state which assembly to load the image from.

What is the correct (and working) way of adding a image resource to a Page from a class libary? (Or does anyone have a working example of ms-appx where the image is in a class library)

Comment: I found an answer that is more simpler. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271863/reference-images-stored-in-external-dll-using-wpf

Comment: @Juan that is WPF, not UWP.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can reproduce this issue. Current workaround I used is copying the resource stream to .NET memory stream.

```
        var assembly = typeof(CookModule).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;

        using (var imageStream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("UWP.ClassLibrary.210644575939381015.jpg"))
        using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            await imageStream.CopyToAsync(memStream);

            memStream.Position = 0;

            using (var raStream = memStream.AsRandomAccessStream())
            {
                var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
                bitmap.SetSource(raStream);

                display.Source = bitmap;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Yeah that definitely works. I don't really understand why though. Shouldn't a Stream be a Stream? Anyway, accepting this answer. It would've taken me quite a while to figure that one out!

Comment: At a guess, and stepping through the debug of it, it's because the GetManifestResourceStream() ends up returning an UnmanagedResourceStream.  We're then copying that over into a managed MemoryStream that managed code can access.