# Some font type can't apply in UWP

Tags: fonts, uwp, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

I found some font type not able to using in UWP.

For example: Noto Sans CJK TC, or Noto Sans(both are Google opensource font)

Even this font already installed in system, or put into app project and using "ms-appx:" or relative path to setting this font.

(Like this question's answer:[UWP - Font only applied in Designer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35465865/uwp-font-only-applied-in-designer), which provide a example, able to using custom font)

When I applied some font, only seen effect in designer but not in run-time.

And there have guideline but which didn't tell how to know which font type isn't able to using in UWP.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/fonts?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Is there have any font type limit in UWP?

Thanks!

Comment: Try uninstalling the app and removing the obj, bin files and try installing it back again. I had the problem once.

Comment: How you use these fonts in your code? Could you share your code? As in my test both Noto Sans and  Noto Sans CJK TC font works well.

Comment: @JayZuo-MSFT I found the problem cause I put page inside folder, but why?... I upload example to bitbucket, change MainPage to UI.BlankPage1 in App.cs, you will see same XAML but UI.BlankPage1 won't apply any font change  [Example on Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/thkaw/uwpfonttest)

Comment: And FontFamily="Assets/fonts/NotoSansCJKtc-Thin.otf#Noto Sans CJK TC" can work, but FontFamily="Assets/fonts/NotoSansCJKtc-Thin.otf#Noto Sans CJK TC Thin" won't.

Noto Sans CJK TC Thin is FontType name which selected by Visual Studio property window, but it won't work.

Comment: I think there may have some problem in my visual studio, my friend help me test this problem by using example which I provide on BitBucket. And result is both page apply font without problem...

Comment: I also try to reference other project font resource in same solution, and UI/BlankPage only use this method that font can be change... that is weird ... I'm trying rebuild another environment to test.

Comment: I try fresh install W10 Insider preview and Visual Studio 2015 update.
But no luck...

2 Windows 10 10586+ 1 Windows 10 Insider preview both are not able to apply font on UI/BlankPage.xaml :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I found the problem cause I put page inside folder, but why?

In you code, you are using following code to set `FontFamily`:

```xaml
FontFamily="Assets/fonts/NotoSansCJKtc-Thin.otf#Noto Sans CJK TC"
```

The URI you've used is a relative URI, It will access files relative to the current XAML page. In your case, while using this in BlankPage1, it will try to access *`Assets/fonts/NotoSansCJKtc-Thin.otf`* file in current folder which is the "UI" folder. As there is no such file in "UI" folder, the `FontFamily` property will use its default value.

To access files relative to the root of the package, from a XAML page, you can use an absolute path URIs (those that begin with a "/") like following:

```xaml
<TextBlock Margin="0,80,0,0"
               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
               FontFamily="/Assets/fonts/NotoSansCJKtc-Thin.otf#Noto Sans CJK TC"
               FontSize="80"
               Foreground="#878787">
    微abc012
</TextBlock>
```

Or using **`ms-appx:`** scheme like following:

```xaml
<TextBlock Margin="0,80,0,0"
           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
           FontFamily="ms-appx:///Assets/fonts/NotoSansCJKtc-Thin.otf#Noto Sans CJK TC"
           FontSize="80"
           Foreground="#878787">
    微abc012
</TextBlock>
```

> And FontFamily="Assets/fonts/NotoSansCJKtc-Thin.otf#Noto Sans CJK TC" can work, but FontFamily="Assets/fonts/NotoSansCJKtc-Thin.otf#Noto Sans CJK TC Thin" won't.

I have the same issue in my side. Form the otf file, its font name should be "Noto Sans CJK TC Thin".
[image]
However using this font name won't work both in XAML Designer and run-time. I think this issue may related to the otf file as I tested with some other fonts, they all worked as expected.

> I also try to reference other project font resource in same solution.

To reference other project font resource in same solution, you can refer to my previous answer in [UWP - Font only applied in Designer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35465865/uwp-font-only-applied-in-designer).

Comment: Oh, thank your help!
In designer seem able to apply, so that I forgot about relative/absolute path!